# Перевод личных имён с латыни на русский, напр. Gaius → Гай (-юс), Julius → Юлий (-ус)

Tags: морфология, ономастика, заимствования, переводы, латиница-кириллица

Почему в русской традиции принято переводить, например, *Гай Юлий Цезарь*, а не *Гаюс Юлиус Цезарь*?

Буду благодарен простой ссылке на материал об истории вопроса (я не смог сформулировать запрос в Google). В поэзии, например, порой встречаются неусечённые формы.

Comment: Традиция и практика общемировая. Если так, то не *почему*, а как..

Comment: Не знаю, насколько это поможет, но... *http://ancientrome.ru/publik/article.htm?a=1343696784*

Comment: shampar, не общемировая. Даже в славянских языках в основном или везде сохраняется латинское написание. Проблема затрагивает языки с другой письменностью, например болгарский, русский, сербский.

Comment: Ольга, спасибо большое!! Содержательная статья, и вы открыли для меня бездонный сайт об античности.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объяснение можно найти в работе [М. Протасова](http://ancientrome.ru/publik/article.htm?a=1343696784).

Ниже приведены некоторые выдержки из этой работы.

> Тран­скрип­ция гре­че­ских и рим­ских соб­ст­вен­ных имен в нашей
> исто­ри­че­ской и худо­же­ст­вен­ной лите­ра­ту­ре, как извест­но,
> име­ет доволь­но хао­ти­че­ский вид и не регу­ли­ру­ет­ся ника­ки­ми
> твер­ды­ми нор­ма­ми.

...

> 3. Самый спо­соб обра­зо­ва­ния соб­ст­вен­ных имен в их рус­ской пере­да­че не регу­ли­ру­ет­ся еди­ным прин­ци­пом; почти в рав­ном
>    коли­че­стве слу­ча­ев исполь­зу­ют­ся два раз­лич­ных спо­со­ба:
>
> а) соб­ст­вен­ные име­на про­из­во­дят­ся от no­mi­na­tiv’а, при­чем,
> вопре­ки зако­нам рус­ской грам­ма­ти­ки, сохра­ня­ют в отдель­ных
> слу­ча­ях гре­че­ские и латин­ские флек­сии: ος, ον, us, um, is;
>
> б) или же соб­ст­вен­ное имя про­из­во­дит­ся от осно­вы с
> при­со­еди­не­ни­ем к ней рус­ско­го окон­ча­ния, чаще все­го с
> нуле­вой флек­си­ей.
>
> Вот два ряда наи­бо­лее типич­ных слу­ча­ев: гео­гра­фи­че­ские име­на
> с гре­че­ски­ми окон­ча­ни­я­ми: Делос (Δῆ­λος), Самос (Σά­μος), Родос
> (Ῥό­δος), Лес­бос (Λέσ­βος), Или­он (Ἴλιον), Амфи­по­лис (Ἀμφί­πολις),
> Мега­ло­по­лис (Με­γαλό­πολις), но Акро­поль, а не Акро­по­лис
> (Ἀκρό­πολις), Неа­поль, а не Неа­по­лис (Νεάπο­λις); с латин­ски­ми
> окон­ча­ни­я­ми: Лаци­ум с.106 (La­tium), Сам­ни­ум (Sam­nium),
> Туску­лум (Tus­cu­lum), Гер­ку­ла­нум (Her­cu­la­num), Реги­ум
> (Re­gium).
>
> В труде проф. Сер­ге­е­ва в общей кар­тине невы­дер­жан­но­сти его
> тран­скрип­ции встре­ча­ют­ся оба спо­со­ба, при­чем даже в пере­да­че
> одно­го и того же име­ни: на стр. 28 мы нахо­дим имя «Ян» (Ianus), а
> на стр. 34 имя того же бога — в обыч­ной фор­ме «Янус»; имя вождя
> наем­ни­ков, вое­вав­ших с Кар­фа­ге­ном, — Мато (Matho), хоро­шо
> извест­ное и при­выч­ное нам по рома­ну Фло­бе­ра «Салам­бо», у проф.
> Сер­ге­е­ва транс­кри­би­ру­ет­ся Мафон.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз.

Answer (score 1):

Это всего лишь предположение.
В русском языке для имён и терминов не характерно *-ус* и *-ос* в конце. Возможно, поэтому. Может, *-us* — что-то типа суффикса и поэтому позволили себе обойтись без него. В русском у имён вроде нет суффиксов, не считая уменьшительно-ласкательных.
Возьмём слово "догмат" — по оригиналу должно быть "догматос".

Comment: То, что русский язык в момент знакомства с греческой и латинской культурой калькировал (то есть заменяет иноязычные аффиксы латинские и греческие слова на существующие или более благозвучные русские, например tion → ция), в принципе, общеизвестно в среде лингвистов.

Comment: Здесь ситуация другая — в том, что речь идёт о личных именах, где выделить-то аффиксы крайне тяжело. Поэтому мне неясно, почему было принято такое решение (а в ином славянском — противоположное). Кстати, правило было бы не правилом, если бы не список исключений для немалого числа имён :)

Comment: Крайне сложно может быть нам, а знающим тот язык — нет. Наверно, просто связано с тем, что по-русски "Юлиус" — "Юлий". А "Гаюс Юлий" — было бы тупо. Многие имена переводятся, потому что есть русский вариант имени. Почти уверен, что причина в этом.

Comment: Я имел в виду переводчиков, вычленяющих морфемы из полумёртвого языка.

Comment: Переводчики — как раз те, кто обязан знать язык.

Comment: У вас логическая ошибка. Наоборот: имя Юлий есть потому, что его заимствовали именно в такой форме. «Гаюс Юлиус» было бы тупо из-за неединообразия.

Comment: "Гаюс Юлий" то есть.

Comment: Не вижу логической ошибки. Русский вариант имени мог существовать до того, как переводили имя Цезаря.